# query is getting spool out in teradata

Tags: teradata

I am executing below queries , but one query is giving me resultand other is giving me [Error 2646] [SQLState HY000] No more spool space in USER.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT PARTITION
    FROM  DB.TABLE 
     ORDER BY PARTITION  ASC;

Error:-[Error 2646] [SQLState HY000] No more spool space in USER.
```

But when i am executing it is giving me results:-

```
 select * from (
 SELECT DISTINCT PARTITION
    FROM  DB."TABLE") x
    ORDER BY X.PARTITION ASC;
```

Answer (score 3):

Teradata's optimizer usually checks if a `DISTINCT` can be rewritten using `GROUP BY` (and vice versa).

In your 1st query it choose *distinct* processing (which is redistribution followed by a *sort*) because of the `ORDER BY` (of course this is stupid).

Derived Tables using `DISTINCT` will not be fwolded, i.e. the optimizer will materialize it. Without the `DISTINCT` it applies the aggregate rewrite which does a AMP-local aggregation as 1st step greatly reducing spool usage.

If you add `COUNT(*)` to #1 it will not spool out and return useful information :)

On the other hand, if I wanted to know about partitions with data I would query `dbc.Stats`...

Comment: @dnoeth...Many thanks for your valuable information.Actually the first query was created by TDCH(Teradata connector for hadoop) , so i ran second query to check whether it works or not . My table is huge, MVC compressed one with 240 GB data. I cannot query stats as query is generated and executed by the TDCH internally. However what i understood that in second case , first distinct partitions will be searched and then order by done , so it avoid redistribution of the data , right??

Comment: @anwaar_hell: Yep, DISTINCT redistributes all rows before eliminating duplicates while GROUP BY removes duplicates before redistribution.